# Request response from Google Search API

Tags: xml, http, google-search-api

I am very much new to Google search API.I need to bring search results to my Java client from specific websites.As a part I created a free Google search-engine api and received cx code.But I tried this url over browser:

```
"http://www.google.com/search?start=0&num=10&q=red+sox&cr=countryIN&client=google-csbe&output=xml_no_dtd&cx=00*******************:****-l****8";
```

But what I get is:

```
<GSP VER="3.2">
<ERROR>403</ERROR>
<TM>0.061511</TM>
<Q>red sox</Q>
<PARAM name="start" value="0" original_value="0" url_escaped_value="0" js_escaped_value="0"/>
<PARAM name="num" value="10" original_value="10" url_escaped_value="10" js_escaped_value="10"/>
.
.
.
```

I'm using free version ,I have not exceeded free usage limit. I crosschecked cx codes and are perfect.
As I goto this url:`https://www.google.com:443/cse/publicurl?cx=00**************:****-l****8`
 I'm getting a good search bar where I get search results from prescribed sites. Do I require any authentication even while checking with url?Could anyone help with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved: Apart from creating a search engine we also need to create custom search engine [CSE/GSS JSON API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/overview). By registering over there we get an api key. Using both these api key and cx codes we need to build our request url [accordingly](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/json-api/v1/using_rest). The output would be in JSON format.